# how can transform a matrix matlab into file .txt?

Tags: matlab, file, matrix

I have a matrix proba (size :10 * 5).

```
proba=[0.5 0.3 0.8 0.9 0.8;
     0.50 0.36 0.58 0.58 0.98;
     0.1 0.25 0.6 0.8 0.9;
     0.5 0.3 0.8 0.9 0.8;
    0.2 0.9 0.58 0.58 0.69;
    0.58 0.14 0.1 0.2 0.3;
    0.25 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.5;
    0.58 0.69 0.25 0.1 0.1;
    0.1 0.25 0.36 0.2 0.3;
   0.5 0.3 0.8 0.9 0.8 ];
```

I want to transform this matrix into a text file (proba.txt) with which the index column is written and the value of the column for each line as follows :

```
 1 0.5 2 0.3 3 0.8 4 0.9 5 0.8
 1 0.50 2 0.36 3 0.58 4 0.58 5 0.98
             .
             .
             .
 1 0.5 2 0.3 3 0.8 4 0.9 5 0.8
```

Please I need help, how can I do it?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function, it is useful for every matrix.

```
function data = addIndex(X)
    [r, c] = size(X);
    index = ones(r, 1);
    data = zeros(r, 2 * c);
    for i = 1:c
        data(:, 2 * i - 1) = i .* index;
        data(:, 2 * i) = X(:, i);
    end
    dlmwrite('proba.txt', data, '\t')
end
```

Comment: I tried this code but I found the same result as the other program I want to have like this 1 0.5 2 0.3 ....

Comment: [result](http://7xj2h9.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/QQ20150520-1@2x.png) this is my result, but I think this method is inflexible, If you have other matrix, I think it's better to use a function.

Comment: I do not open the link but as you said this method does not work with a large size of  matrix

Comment: I wrote a function for you, now you can pass every matrix into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this using [dlmwrite](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html), but first you want to add the column of indexes in front of your matrix:

```
function result = writematrix(proba)
rowind = 1:size(proba,2);
for t = 1:size(proba,1);
     C(t,:,:) =  [rowind',proba(t,:)']';
     D(t,:) =  C(t(:),:);

end

dlmwrite('filename.txt',D,'\t') %//I assume you want tab delimiter, if you want space, it is ' ' instead
%//dlmwrite('filename.txt',D,' ')
end
```

Note that this will write the text file into your local directory, and that it only works for numerical values, not strings, for strings, it is better to use csvwrite.

EDIT : Ops, didn't read the question fully, this should now work fine.

Comment: by running this program, I did not get the result that I want, I like display the index of the column and its value

Comment: @sahar try this now, it should work fine. I didn't read the question properly, apologies.

Comment: error : Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in test_version3 (line 17)
     C(t,:,:) =  [rowind',proba(t,:)']';

Comment: can you redisplay the function that you have implemented? because this is the solution that I'm looking for